# Linq: Join 2 tables that share one column name (with different data)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, linq-to-sql

There are several questions regarding this topic on stackoverflow but I couldn't find the answer to my problem.

I have tried to join the table COSTS with the table CREDITS. My problem is that I want to access the 'label' property (which exists on both tables) after the join. This is obviously not possible anymore because they were 'merged' during the join. **I must state that despite the fact that the properties 'label' share the same name, they do not contain the same information.**

To solve the problem, I have tried to use the 'let' keyword, but unfortunatelly the intellisense doesn't recognize my 'costLabel' variable (last line).

```
var query = from cost in COSTS
                    let costLabel = cost.Label
                    join credit in CREDITS
                    on cost.IdCredit equals credit.IdCredit into joined
                    from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new SearchCredit
                    {
                        CreditLabel = j.Label,
                        CostLabel = costLabel
                    };
```

Comment: Check this question out: Join with an anonymous type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705922/linq-join-with-same-name-on-different-tables

Comment: You don't need the `let`. Just type `CostLabel = cost.Label` in your select statement. `cost.` referes back to the COST table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
var query = from cost in COSTS
                join credit in CREDITS
                on cost.IdCredit equals credit.IdCredit into joined
                from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new SearchCredit
                {
                    CreditLabel = j.Label,
                    CostLabel = cost.Label
                };
```